Magic Leap 2 distance for Vuforia Model Target
I'm testing different object models with Magic Leap 2 and Vuforia Engine Model Target and it's seems that I need to be very near (about 5 cm) of the object in order that the Vuforia Engine  recognize it and track it. Is there any limitation for the size of the model?
I use small target models around 6 x 2 x 5 cm with Advanced Model Target.

I would say, yes, there is a limit to how small Model Targets can be. But it all depends on your use case. Do users go close as part of the AR experience or are they meant to discover these objects by "scanning a room for objects"?
In the Vuforia documentation, it says

The cameras on a digital eyewear device, however, are located on the user's head. Therefore, targets need to be detectable and trackable from greater distances. Also, most devices have near field clipping planes, which will stop rendering if you move too close to a target.

Which means using eyewear, objects should generally be larger for Vuforia Engine to detect at larger distance, and being too close to the object will likely clip the rendering with the near field plane.
Another point is whether the objects carry sufficient detail. Are they complex enough to provide enough features for Vuforia Engine to detect it? This Best Practices guide has details on what makes a well-tracking object. It includes: geometric detail, rigid, CAD-model accuracy, texturing, etc.
